Power BI Connection to SQL Server
Trying to connect to SQL Server via Power BI.
I can get there using SSMS, but Power BI gives me:

We encountered an error while trying to connect.  Details: "Microsoft SQL: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake.  (provider: TCP Provider, error:0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)"

Any suggestions as to where I should start?  Using the same connection parameters from SSMS in Power BI - so figured it'd work, but no luck.

What version of SQL Server? (What does PRINT @@VERSION return?) My guess; you are using an unsupported and unpatched version of SQL Server.

2022 (RTM-CU14-GDR) (KB0542578) - 16.0.4140.3 (X64)

2022 (RTM-CU15) (KB5041321) - 16.0.4145.4 (X64) - just updated it right now.  same problem.

I'm no expert, but doesn't one usually need Gateways etc to be able to connect PowerBI with SQL Server?

@siggemannen. The OP might mean Power BI "desktop" and so direct connection is possible.

I typically get this kind of message when firewall rules are the issue or ports are blocked. If possible, temporarily switch off the firewall on your client machine and see if that changes anything. If so then you'll need to check what rules are in place, it might be that SSMS is allowed via whatever security service is in place.
